# apt-get throws 400 URI failure when trying to download docker-ce

Tags: debian, docker, apt

I'm having a strange issue with trying to install docker-ce instead of the outdated distro packages on Debian Stretch. I followed their simple guide verbatim:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/

The key is present and verified and the sources.list line generated looks fine as expected:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

However, a complete re-download of the package lists (stretch, stretch-updates and debian-security otherwise) results in this:

```
W: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/binary-amd64/Packages
```

Complete `apt-get update` output:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease                      
Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch Release                  
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages    
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages      
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en    
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en_US 
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Contents (deb)
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch all Contents (deb)      
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch amd64 Contents (deb)    
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages    
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages      
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en    
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en_US 
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Contents (deb)
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch all Contents (deb)      
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch amd64 Contents (deb)    
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages    
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages      
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en    
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en_US 
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Contents (deb)
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch all Contents (deb)      
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch amd64 Contents (deb)    
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en_US
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Contents (deb)
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch all Contents (deb)
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en_US
Get:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main Sources [195 kB]
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Contents (deb)
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch all Contents (deb)
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch amd64 Contents (deb)
Err:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages

Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable Translation-en_US
Get:13 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [476 kB]
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Contents (deb)
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch all Contents (deb)      
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch amd64 Contents (deb)   
Get:14 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main Translation-en [211 kB]
Ign:15 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                         
Get:16 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]            
Get:17 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]    
Get:18 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main Sources [14.3 kB]
Get:19 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [11.1 kB]
Get:20 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main Translation-en [11.1 kB]
Get:21 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Contents (deb) [352 kB]
Get:22 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2,434 B]
Get:23 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main Sources [6,746 kB]
Get:24 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7,084 kB]
Get:25 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main Translation-en [5,384 kB]
Get:26 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Contents (deb) [31.4 MB]
Fetched 52.2 MB in 13s (3,784 kB/s)                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/binary-amd64/Packages  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Both `curl` and `wget` pull the exact URLs apt is complaining about without issues and show nothing of note in their verbose logs.

Looking at `strace`, I see this:

```
read(5, "400 URI Failure\nURI: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/binary-all/Packages\nMessage: \n\n400 URI Failure\nURI: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/binary-amd64/Packages\nMessage: \n\n400 URI Failure\nURI: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/i18n/Translation-en\nMessage: \n\n400 URI Failure\nURI: https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/i18n/Translation-en_US\nMessage: \n\n", 64000) = 461
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.docker.com_linux_debian_dists_stretch_stable_binary-all_Packages", 0x7ffded218d60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.docker.com_linux_debian_dists_stretch_stable_binary-all_Packages") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/download.docker.com_linux_debian_dists_stretch_Contents-all.lz4", 0x7ffded218b80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.docker.com_linux_debian_dists_stretch_Contents-all", 0x7ffded218bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(1, "Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages\n", 75Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable all Packages
) = 75
stat("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.docker.com_linux_debian_dists_stretch_stable_binary-amd64_Packages", 0x7ffded218d60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.docker.com_linux_debian_dists_stretch_stable_binary-amd64_Packages") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(1, "Err:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages\n", 77Err:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
```

That 400 URI failure has been discussed before, e. g. here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/493180/method-gave-invalid-400-uri-failure-message-when-running-apt-get-update#497377

However, it doesn't appear to be the same locale issue - running the same test with `wget` I see it uses `en_US.UTF-8` and this is my `locale` output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So, nothing too special. This is pretty much a bog-standard Debian Stretch install with not much else done than getting `apache2`, `sendmail`, `dovecot` and other standard applications like them.

I do not have a proxy configured in $http_proxy, in any of the profile / bashrc files or for apt specifically. I can't find a good open HTTPS proxy and seem to be unable to throw one together but one that let a few bytes trickle through showed the 400 errors as well so it's unlikely that my VPS provider is pulling some shady trick on me. (If they even could with HTTPS - I'm with RamNode who recommend one of their KVMs for Docker use.) My Sid desktop with a much more hacky configuration has no issues downloading the files, as did someone on the Docker IRC using Stretch, which is at least a bit strange.

I'm out of ideas and will have to install manually for now, which works but is of course not a good idea. Any guesses on what the problem could be?

**Edit:** OK, I'm at my wits' end here. I set up `mitmproxy` in order to capture the traffic to `download.docker.com`. I configured it as a reverse proxy, put the proxy IP in the `hosts` table as `download.docker.com` and executed `apt-get update` again. It goes through flawlessly, the requests look like completely normal HTTP/1.1 in Wireshark and go through in `openssl` as well. The encoding is simply ASCII(-compatible).

If someone knows how to explain this, please do. I could MITM `mitmproxy` (straight to port 80 not possible because of forced HTTPS) and compare the incoming and outgoing requests on the proxy system but I doubt it will yield anything and I already have a headache...

Edit2: Testes with a second Debian Stable machine (which updates correctly) as a comparison. The requests sent by them are the same, byte for byte according to Wireshark.

Comment: Weird, there appears to be a Release & Release.gpg file at https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/ and in https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/binary-amd64/ could try downloading them & verify with gpg? `man apt-secure` also mentions two (insecure?) workarounds. But https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/stable/binary-all/Packages from the strace does 404 error...

Comment: Try: Use synaptic to delete all broken packages.

Comment: @Xen2050, none of the files are downloaded - it can't be a verification error. And even the URI that 404s (probably being checked by default or something) gets a 400 error instead. 400 is "bad request", i. e. _something_ doesn't understand what my system wants. Encoding problem would make sense but looks like it's not that.

harrymc, this is a CLI only server. I have no broken packages, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution (sort of)**

It works through `mitmproxy` because I disabled certificate validation for it - with that configuration, I don't need the proxy. I have no idea how a failed certificate validation can lead to a 400 error because the HTTP communication shouldn't happen in the first place but there's clearly something happening here that's beyond my level of expertise. At least there's a workaround to try if someone has a similar problem with an HTTPS repo...

Comment: Did you follow the step to "allow apt to use a repository over HTTPS"?

Comment: @Biswapriyo, sure, I followed the same tutorial on both systems. (About ten times over on the failing one...) What I forgot above, `ca-certificates` is on the same version on both systems so it's not that. (Current 9.8 update status without backports on both.)